# Encoding Bounding Boxes using Conv1D

Tags: python, encoding, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I'm working on a project where I need to encode bounding boxes using a Conv1D neural network. However, I'm encountering some challenges with the input and output sizes during the forward pass. Here's the setup:

I have implemented a Conv1DModule class in PyTorch to perform Conv1D operations. The module is defined as follows:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class Conv1DModule(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, output_size, kernel_size=3, stride=1):
        super(Conv1DModule, self).__init__()
        self.conv1d = nn.Conv1d(input_size, output_size, kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=stride)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.transpose(1, 2)
        x = self.conv1d(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        return x
```

When I pass input data with size [batch_size, input_size, seq_length] through this module, I notice a change in the sequence length during the forward pass.

Here's a sample of the output:

Input size: torch.Size([8, 4, 14])
After convolution: torch.Size([8, 32, 12])

As you can see, the input has a size of [8, 4, 14], indicating a batch size of 8, sequence length of 14, and input size of 36. However, after applying the convolution, the sequence length changes to 12 instead of remaining the same.

My goal is to encode bounding boxes using this Conv1D module, but the changing sequence length is causing issues with the encoding process.

Could anyone please help me understand why the sequence length is changing during the Conv1D operation and how I can ensure it remains the same throughout the process?